# change values in html based on database input

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to develop an application in which it is very important to detect changes in a database in real time. I have devised a method to detect the changes now by running an ajax function and refreshing the page every 3 seconds, but this is not very efficient at all, and on high stress levels it dosen't seem like an effective solution.

Is there any way I can detect if some change has been made in the database instantly without having to refresh the page? The sample code is attached. I'm using php as my server side language, with html/css as the front end.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#div-unassigned-request-list').load("atc_unassigned_request_list.php");
$('#div-driver-list').load("atc_driver_list.php");
$('#div-assigned-request-list').load("atc_assigned_request_list.php");
$('#div-live-trip-list').load("atc_live_trip_list.php");

setInterval(function() {

    $.ajax({url:"../methods/method_get_current_time.php",success:function(result){
        $("#time").html(result);
    }});


}, 1000)

setInterval( function() {

    $.ajax({url:"atc_unassigned_request_list.php",success:function(result){
        $("#div-unassigned-request-list").html(result);
    }});

    $.ajax({url:"atc_driver_list.php",success:function(result){
        $("#div-driver-list").html(result);
    }});

    $.ajax({url:"atc_assigned_request_list.php",success:function(result){
        $("#div-assigned-request-list").html(result);
    }});

} ,2000);
```

});

Please help!

Comment: have a look at the `websocket`-protocol! With that you can push updates from the server to the browser when db changes.

Comment: you can use also `Server Sent Events` if browser compatibility is not a big issue. Read these links-> http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For me, the best solution is

- On the server side write a service that identify the changes
- On the client, check this service  with [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) preferencially (or ajax if you can not use websockets), then if there have changes, download it, This way you have, economy and velocity with more funcionality

### Examples Updated

Using ajax

```
function downloadUpdates(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'have-changes.php'
            success:function(response){
                if(response == 'yes'){
                    // ok, let`s download the changes
                    ...
                    
                    // after download updates let`s start new updates check (after success ajax method of the update code)
                    downloadUpdates(); 
                }else{
                    downloadUpdates();
                }
            }
        });
    }, 3000);
}
downloadUpdates();
```

Using websockets

```
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://www.example.com/changesServer");
exampleSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
  if(event.data != "no"){
        // ok here are the changes
        $("body").html(event.data);
    }
}
exampleSocket.onopen = function (event) {
    // testing it
    setInterval(function(){
        exampleSocket.send("have changes?");
    }, 3000)
}
```

[Here (I have tested it )](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket) and [Here](http://socketo.me/docs/install) some examples of how to use websocokets on php, the problem is **you will need to have shell access**